# App killed from task manager is called foreground state or background state

Tags: applications, task-management, processes

If I close app from task manager by doing-- Press home-button for a long time -> see all running apps -> swipe my app aside -> All app killed.

Now those apps I have removed from task manager is in background or foreground?
If app open in task manager is called background?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Apps foreground/background process depends on memory management of your device.

Let's say in your task manager you're running 8 apps and out of 8 you're currently using 3 apps via continuous switching among these 3 apps then your device will see your usage and it could trigger rest 5 apps to run in background for a while but if you don't use those 5 apps for much time then those apps could be triggered to sleep to **save power and CPU consumption** until you open them again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please tell me the names of all 3 states like app Open, open in task manager & totally closed.